# Can I increase the specificity of a variable in a class extending another class in java?

Tags: java, class, extends

I'm developing a game in which I use a handler object to handle all rendering and ticking behavior. Each `scene` corresponds to a different `handler` object. Each of my handlers has a set of methods that are specific to that type of handler. For example, only the level handler has `addPlayer` and `addEnemy` methods.

I want to define a generic `Scene` class like this:

```
public class Scene {
    protected Handler handler;

    public Scene(Handler handler){
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        handler.render(g);
    }
}
```

I'd then like to define a subclass of my scene, which will be the scene object specific to when the player is playing the game, called `levelScene`:

```
public class LevelScene extends Scene {
    protected LevelHandler; //<- This doesn't work.
}
```

I'd like to access the methods which are specific to `LevelHandler` within `LevelScene`, while letting the `Scene` class handle rendering and ticking with the handler. It seems like the best way to go about doing so would be to specify that, for my `LevelScene` class, the handler is a `LevelHandler`, which is a class that extends `Handler`. What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Sounds like `Handler` needs to be an interface and `LevelHandler` should be an implementation of that interface. If `Handler` is a class and `LevelHandler` extends that class you can still assign it to a variable of type `Handler`. To access `LevelHandler` specific methods, you need to mask the `LevelHandler` and operate on the masked variable.

Comment: Or some abstract superclasses and methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using generics. That way the `Scene` superclass treats your handler like any other handler, but `LevelScene` ensures that it's a LevelHandler.

```
public class Scene<HandlerType extends Handler> {
    protected HandlerType handler;

    public Scene(HandlerType handler){
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        handler.render(g);
    }
}
```

Then your subclass can be

```
public class LevelScene extends Scene<LevelHandler> {
    @Override
    public void render(Graphics g) {
        super(g);
        handler.doLevelOnlyThing();
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm!